# Every function with Object.values not working

Tags: javascript

I have an object and I need to check if all the values are true.

```
{
  condition1: true, 
  condition2: true,
  condition3: false
}
```

Ive used Object.value to get an array of the true and false values. However I cant seem to get the every function to work, it always returns true.

```
const test = Object.values(equipmentSelection)
  .every((element) => {
    if (element = true) return true;
  });
```

Comment: You're always returning `true` due to that assignment operator. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: you're assigning `element` to be `true`

Comment: You have a single equals sign in your conditional. I'm sure this is just a typo, but just to reiterate, a sign equals sign assigns and a double equals signs compares.

Comment: Simply use `.every(element => element)`

Comment: Please try to replace `if (element = true) return true;` to `return element;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the element without using conditional check, you can do like this

```
 const test = Object.values(equipmentSelection)
  .every(element => element)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an assignment operator `=` instead of a logical `==` or `===` operator. So you are basically setting `element` to be equal to `true` and then use this same value (`true`) as the condition of `if`. So the `if` condition is always `true` and thus `true` is returned for each element in the array.

Since `element` is of type boolean, you don't need the `if` statement, just use its value:

```
.every(element => element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
const test = Object.values(equipmentSelection)
   .every(element => element===true);
```

And like others have said,

```
.every( element => element);
```

Will return the elements value which is with true or false and that’s what you will get with the comparisons.